# New way of displaying votes in user profile

Tags: discussion, voting

Is it only me (for example because I reached some rep., got some badge...) or did you also mentioned new votes counts in user profile ?

If it is new staff do you like it ? I personally appreciate more detailed statistics but I think for new users the previous display was better (very intuitive to read, not too much details).

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you're talking about this:

[image: Screenshot of the "Votes Cast" box]

It came out in the last day or two. Personally I think it's fine; the old view showed arrows, while this one says "up"/"down". The total counts are in the first column, so you can ignore the rest if you want

Comment: Arrows are supposed to be more intuitive when it comes to human perception. Or faster to perceive. But that is indeed questionable... Humans should perceive symbols that faster and better then text - by making an association with the same symbols shown after upvote. But we geeks might be exception :).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, upon reflection, I kind of agree with this. I very much like that they've provided us with such detailed statistics about our (and others!) voting patterns. But the information *is* considerably more dense, and thus more difficult to parse for both newbies and experienced users alike. The upvote and downvote symbols next to the total vote count were very user-friendly and quite easy to understand.

**I propose that the two designs be combined.** The total vote count could still be presented as the most prominent data, using the up-arrow/down-arrow sprites for instant visual recognition, while keeping all of the other useful statistical data that has been added to the right.

I'm not much of a designer, though, so I'm not even going to try and create a mockup. I'll leave that task to the excellent UX engineers here.

Comment: Excellent answer!!! I completely agree and support what you propose. I'm no designer either but I have strong professional interest in user interfaces in terms of usability etc. And I think that something like what you propose would be the best. Removing the arrows was move in wrong direction in my opinion. Well I could provide some mock-up but I guess it would need some user-testing of my ideas to be valuable so I guess if the guys from SO team are interested in improving this staff they will do the mock-up them selfs.